# Address elment by number from differnet parents using xpath

Tags: dom, xpath

So I have this DOM structure

```
<body>
    <div>
        <a></a>
        <a></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

I can access two first link element by using xpath:

```
//div/a[1] 
//div/a[2]
```

And I want to access 3rd link by using same xpath structure (to enumerate them all)

```
//div/a[3]
```

But this method fails, because link elements have different parent div's
Any way to correct my xpath to access all link elements by it's number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use parenthesis:

```
 (//div/a)[3]
```